# Excel VBA, Read and count word without opening files (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite a beginner for coding VBA of excel. Right now, I am trying to code a very simple function of counting a specific word in a specific column of external workbook file without opening it. 
This function will read line by line.

Here is my code. It counts "n" in the specific column.

```
Public Function ExceptNum(Path As String, Column As String) As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim WBook As Workbook

Dim i As Long
count = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set WBook = Workbooks.Open(Path)
    With WBook.Worksheets(1)
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Range(Column & i).Value = "n" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If

        Next i
     End With
WBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

ExceptNum = count
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

However, When I use my function in worksheet, it returns #VALUE!. I am not sure what I did wrong. The code can be use within VBA code itself. But in the worksheet, it doesn't work.

Moreover, this function will read a thousand of files. Is my function efficient and fast?

Comment: You said you want to do this without opening the files but in reality this `Set WBook = Workbooks.Open(Path)` opens the file you just can't see it because of this line `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: Exactly, I did try other ways. But it didn't work. So I went back and did it this way. Do you know other ways to make this work?

Comment: There is no other way. In order to interact with any object it must be called into memory some way and hence defined and initiated in some way. Otherwise, the object does not exist in scope/context of code. This goes beyond VBA but all programming.